# Disable transfer-encoding chunked in jax-ws

Tags: jax-ws

I made a web service using jax-ws, but I need to disble the transfer-encoding chunked.

I used a handler, similar to this one:

```
public class MyHandler<SOAPMessageContext> implements Handler {

    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext c) {
        if((Boolean)c.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {
            c.put(SOAPMessageContext.HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS,"your header stuff here");
            return true;
        }
    }
 }
```

But I don't know which header is the correct one to disable the chunked encoding.